# integrable vs. measurable, can the premise in this statement be relaxed?

Tags: measure-theory

I had this excercise:

[image: pic]

Is it ok to assume that f is measurable instead?, or do we need the integrability? When i solved it I did not use that the integral was finite, so is measurability enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be measurable and $f=0$ a.e.

Then the nonnegative $f^{+}$ defined by $x\mapsto\max\left(f\left(x\right),0\right)$
and $f^{-}$ defined by $x\mapsto\max\left(-f\left(x\right),0\right)$
have these properties too.

Then $$\int f^{+}d\mu=0=\int f^{-}d\mu$$
and consequently $$\int fd\mu:=\int f^{+}d\mu-\int f^{-}d\mu=0$$
So indeed it is enough for $f$ to be measurable.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. In fact, we needn't assume $f$ is (Lebesgue) measurable. Any function which is zero a.e. is automatically (Lebesgue) measurable and integrable.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that 0 a.e. -> measurable? That is how do we know that $f^{-1}[-\infty,r)$, is in the $\sigma$-algebra? I mean we know that the subsets $\{x: f(x)=0\}$, and $\{x: f(x)\ne0\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra, but why can't there be complicated sets of the form $f^{-1}[-\infty,r)$ which for instance may be a subset of the second which is not in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha \geq 0$. Then $\{f > \alpha\}$ is a set of measure zero, hence measurable. Otherwise $\alpha < 0$ and $\{f > \alpha\} = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{f \leq \alpha\}$. Since $\{f \leq \alpha\}$ is a set of measure zero, hence measurable, $\{f > \alpha\}$ is measurable too.

Comment: But doesn't that assume that the measure space is complete?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming we were using the Lebesgue measure. I'll edit appropriately. I don't know about other measures; I've never actually studied them.

Comment: For this you need the extra condition that the measure is complete.